# “community wiki” checkbox in new question shows a dialog twice when self-answering

Tags: bug, community-wiki, self-answer, popups

1. [Ask a question;](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
2. Click *Answer your own question*
3. Check *community wiki*
4. A dialog box

   > Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?

   will appear, Click *OK* or *Cancel;*
5. The same dialog will appear again.

Google Chrome 44.0.2403.107 / Windows8.1 / site rev 2015.7.25.3609

Comment: Can you please unaccept the answer? Know it's weird to ask, but in Meta for a bug report, accepted answer should be a developer who actually fix the bug, or explain why it can't be fixed etc. Having it accepted might cause the team to ignore the bug report

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oops, I've just unaccepted it. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: No problem, hopefully devs will see this soon and fix. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was a bit worried as well so I asked [Oded](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4228793#4228793) about how answering would affect bug visibility for the team.

Comment: @rene but the point here was that the answer was accepted, so common sense tells that it means the bug was handled. As it stands, it doesn't matter - this is just one another bug in the 6000-8000 bugs list that will be fixed in 6-8 years. (or not :))

Comment: Sure, good call @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 9):

That seems to be a bug in wmd.js

This line is wiring the click event to be only called one single time:

```
$(".js-post-editor input[type=checkbox][name=communitymode]").one("click", function () {
    return confirm(function (e) {
        return "Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?" + e.blankLine + "Doing so will remove explicit ownership and you will no longer earn reputation for upvotes on it. Once saved, this option cannot be unchecked without moderator assistance."
    }
        ({
            "blankLine" : "\n\n"
        }))
})
```

The jquery selector is `.js-post-editor input[type=checkbox][name=communitymode]`

When the page https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask is served it already contains the answer box with the checkbox but is hidden:

```
<input id="communitymode-42" name="communitymode" type="checkbox" >
```

The WMD editor is however started twice, once for the question and once for the answer:

```
    function createEditor() {
        prepareEditor({
            heartbeatType: '',
            bindNavPrevention: true,
            postfix: "-42", // for the question this is a ""
                onDemand: false,
                discardSelector: ".discard-question"
            ,postId:42
            });
```

As the jquery selector for the checkbox doesn't take the postfix into account, it wires the click event two times, hence the confirmation box showing twice.

I think if the jquery selector in [`02_EditorInitialization.js`](http://dev.sstatic.net/js/wmd.js) is changed to

```
 // community wiki can accidentally be enabled - inform users of this nuclear option
 $('#communitymode' + options.postfix).one('click', function () {
```

it should work as designed.

Expect 6 to 8 units to get this patch pushed.